# Wrong center of mass using scipy ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find the centre of mass on binary images using `ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass` from the Scipy library.

My code goes as follow:

```
def show_keypoints(image, key_point):
    plt.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.scatter(key_point[0],key_point[1], s=20, marker='.', c='lightgreen')


#Loading the image (shape : (576,576) as np.array))
img = load_img(path)
centroid = scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(img)

fig = plt.figure()  
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_title('Label')
show_keypoints(img, centroid)
plt.show()
```

obtain:

[image]

So I checked if I had the right image as input, it's correct, I checked if the image was binary using `np.unique(imgs[i])` got `(array([0, 1], dtype=uint8)`.

I am not sure what's not right here.

Does anyone has an idea?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the order of the arguments to scatter:

```
    plt.scatter(key_point[1], key_point[0], s=20, marker='.', c='lightgreen')
```

`imshow` uses an image-based convention for plotting its data, while `scatter` and `plot` use the usual (x, y) coordinates.

Comment: Wonderfull, thank you very much ! I thought the library was fine but I didn't imagine that it could have been the coordinates display. Thank you very very Warren